# List contents of AWS S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a AWS S3 with the following structure or hierarchy:

- customer/name/firstname/123.gz
- customer/name/firstname/456.gz
- customer/name/firstname/789.gz

I need to get count of all the gz files in customer/name/firstname using java sdk.

Can I please have a Java code on how to do it?

Comment: The Java SDK is documented.  You'll need to take a shot at it, then show us your code and the error or exception or unexpected behavior that you're encountering.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to get list of files from `S3`. This is one of them:

```
/**
 * @bucketName bucket name (i.e. customer)
 * @path       path within given bucket (i.e. name/firstname)
 * @pattern    pattern that matches required files (i.e. "\\w+\\.gz") 
 */
private List<String> getFileList(String bucketName, String path, Pattern pattern) throws AmazonS3Exception {
    ListObjectsV2Request request = createRequest(bucketName, path);

    return s3.listObjectsV2(request).getObjectSummaries().stream()
                               .map(file -> FilenameUtils.getName(file.getKey()))
                               .filter(fileName -> pattern.matcher(fileName).matches())
                               .sorted()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static ListObjectsV2Request createRequest(String bucketName, String path) {
    ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request();
    request.setPrefix(path);
    request.withBucketName(bucketName);
    return request;
}
```

**P.S.** I suppose that you already have `S3` credentials in your home directory and successfully initialized `AmazonS3 s3` instance.